# JDK11 code structure - where is java.exe and jli.dll source code located?

Tags: java, java-11

Here we have an official JDK source code repo:
https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/ and that's a GitHub mirror: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11

I searched across the whole repo and cannot find source code for java.exe and jli.dll native modules. Where are they located? Where is the source code of java.exe?

Comment: This is off-topic for stack overflow, since it's an off-site resource request, but I believe the file for java.exe is: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/native/launcher/main.c

Comment: It is all in the OpenJDK source tree.  You are probably searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: You need to realize that the build system use autoconf to generate the actual makefiles.  Unless you are an autoconf guru, you will need to set up a Windows build box (with cygwin, etc) and go through the build process to identify what specifically goes into those 2 artifacts.

Comment: @JornVernee - That jpackage link gives me a 404.

Comment: @Steve jpackage is part of the JDK itself these days, so there's no more need to download a separate JDK that includes it. e.g. you could just use: http://jdk.java.net/15/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps
jdk/src/java.base/share/native/launcher/main.c

Or rather this is what you want...

jdk/src/java.base/share/native//libjli/java.c